# cacade delete operation not working as expected in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, cascade

i tried implementing cascaded="delete" as follows but only the employee row gets deleted and not the corresponding salary row.
The Employee pojo class is :

```
public class Employee {
int empid;
String ename;
Salary sal;
//gettrs and setters
```

The salary pojo class is :

```
public class Salary {
int sid;
double netsal;
Employee employee;
    //getters and setters
```

the employee.hbm file is :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="employee.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
    <id name="empid" type="int">
        <column name="EMPID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="ename" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="ENAME" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="sal" class="employee.Salary" cascade="delete">
        <column name="sid" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

the salary.hbm file is:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="employee.Salary" table="SALARY">
    <id name="sid" type="int">
        <column name="sid" />
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="netsal" type="double">
        <column name="netsal" />
    </property>
</class>
```

and the corresponding mysql tables are created as:

```
create table employee(EMPID int(5) primary key,ENAME varchar(20),sid int(5),foreign key(sid) references salary(sid));
create table salary(sid int(5) primary key,netsal int(5));
```

after inserting records like:

```
SessionFactory sf= new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    session= sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction();
    Employee emp=new Employee();
    emp.setEmpid(12);
    emp.setEname("some name");
    Salary sal=new Salary();
    sal.setNetsal(12000);
    emp.setSal(sal);
    sal.setEmployee(emp);
    tx.commit();
    session.flush();
    session.close();
```

when i do

```
Query query = session.createQuery("delete from employee e where e.empid=12");
    query.executeUpdate();
```

then the  entry in the employee table is deleted but the corresponding entry in salary table remains.So how do i ensure that the corresponding salary entry is also deleted?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cascade doesn't work when deleting entities using DML-style delete queries. It will work only if you delete the employee using the session:

```
Employee e = (Employee) session.load(Employee.class, 12);
session.delete(e);
```